# Gerador de Imagem não Funciona

Tags: php, imagem, código-de-barras

```
<pre>
<code>    
<?php
$tamanhofonte = 100;
// Fonte de código de barras que eu tenho em um sistema
$fonte = 'c39hrp48dhtt.ttf';

// Texto que será impresso na imagem
// Para que funcione com leitores é necessário
// que seja iniciado e finalizado a String com o caracter '*'
$texto = "*" . $_GET['nome'] . "*";

// Retorna o tamanho da imagem criada pela fonte acima carregada.
$tamanho = imagettfbbox($tamanhofonte, 0, $fonte, $texto);
$largura = $tamanho[2] + $tamanho[0] + 8;
$altura = abs($tamanho[1]) + abs($tamanho[7]);

// cria a imagem exatamente do tamanho informado pelo imagettfbbox
$imagem = imagecreate($largura, $altura);
/* @Parametros
 * $largura - Largura que deve ser criada a imagem
 * $altura - Altura que deve ser criada a imagem
 */

// Primeira chamada do imagecolorallocate cria a cor de fundo da imagem
imagecolorallocate($imagem, 255, 255, 255);

// As demais chamadas criam cores para serem usadas na imagem
$preto = imagecolorallocate($imagem, 0, 0, 0);

// Adiciona o texto a imagem
imagefttext($imagem, $tamanhofonte, 0, 0, abs($tamanho[5]), $preto, $fonte, $texto);
/* @Parametros
 * $imagem - Imagem previamente criada Usei imagecreate.
             poderia ter usado o imagecreatefromjpeg
 * $tamanhofonte - Tamanho da fonte em pixel
 * 0 - Posição X do texto na imagem
 * 0 - Posição Y do texto na imagem
 * abs($tamanho[5]) - Corrige o Y
 * $preto - Cor do texto
 * $fonte - Caminho relativo ou absoluto da fonte a ser carregada.
 * $texto - Texto que deverá ser escrito
 */

// Header informando que é uma imagem JPEG
header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );

// eEnvia a imagem para o borwser ou arquivo
imagejpeg( $imagem, NULL, 80 );
/* @Parametros
 * $imagem - Imagem previamente criada Usei imagecreatefromjpeg
 * NULL - O caminho para salvar o arquivo. 
          Se não definido ou NULL, o stream da imagem será mostrado diretamente. 
 * 80 - Qualidade da compresão da imagem.
 */
?>
</code>
```

Este código era para gerar um código de barras para Leitor mas ele da um erro como: The image "arquivo" cannot be displayed because contained errors.

Alguem poderia ajudar?

Comment: Não há nenhum erro: http://i.imgur.com/OMH5eo1.png, porém você deve ter o [`c39hrp48dhtt.ttf`](http://www.dafont.com/pt/c39hrp48dhtt.font) no MESMO diretorio do arquivo php, neste caso. Ou seja, `teste.php` e `c39hrp48dhtt.ttf` estão no mesmo diretório.

Comment: Olha o que aconteceu no meu: http://imgur.com/a/2AetS

Answer (score 1):

Não há nenhum erro no código, como comentei acima. Entretanto presumo, no puro achismo, que o problema seja porque o arquivo da fonte não está no local especificado, quando diz que "Fonte de código de barras que eu tenho em um sistema" não fica claro se a fonte está no local dito ou se está querendo usar uma fonte já instalada no dispositivo.

Se você especifica o `c39hrp48dhtt.ttf`, você deve possuir algo assim:

```
C:.
    c39hrp48dhtt.ttf
    teste.php
```

Dessa forma o `teste.php` poderá ler a fonte que especificou em `$fonte = 'c39hrp48dhtt.ttf';`, pois ambos estão no mesmo diretório.

Se você quiser usar uma fonte já "instalada" precisará saber onde ocorre tal instalação no seu sistema operacional, onde a fonte se encontra.

No caso do Windows o local é `C:\Windows\Fonts`, você pode utilizar o `%WINDIR%\Fonts`, para ficar mais fácil.

Logo você poderá utilizar:

```
$fonte = getenv('windir').'/Fonts/c39hrp48dhtt.ttf';
// Irá utilizar C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/c39hrp48dhtt.ttf
```

*Dessa forma irá consumir a fonte que já está disponível no seu sistema.*

> Além disso remova o `<pre>` e `<code>` do código, deixando somente o PHP, afinal você está dando em `Content-type: image/jpeg`.

Comment: Dessa parte da fonte eu já sabia mas, não sei se isso influência mas estou hospedando no meu Ubuntu.

Comment: O <pre> e <code> não estavam no código, uma pessoa corrigiu.

Poderia passar o código completo?

Comment: Utilizei exatamente o http://freetexthost.com/0kafgtav45 e funcionou normalmente.